# What is the use of this class<T>

Tags: c#

The following code I saw in one of StackOverflow sites. But it is not explained in detail and I am unable to understand. Would anyone explain this?

```
public class MyArray<T>
{
    T[] array = new T[10];
    public T GetItem(int index)
    {
        return array[index];
    }
}
```

1. I would like to know if this is a class.
2. How to instantiate this class?
3. How can I use the T array in the class?
4. Whether the array need to be created outside or inside in the class?

Comment: This is called generics: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Generic classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx) `<T>` have type parameters. Separate classes, each with a different field type in them, can be replaced with a single generic class. The generic class introduces a type parameter. This becomes part of the class definition itself. It allows you to define type-safe data structures, without committing to actual data types. The most common use of generics is to create collection classes. This results in a significant performance boost and higher quality code, because you get to reuse data processing algorithms without duplicating type-specific code.

The letter `T` denotes a type that is only known based on the calling location. The program can act upon the instance of `T` like it is a real type, but it is not.

> I would like to know if this is a class.

Yes it is a class

> How to instantiate this class?

```
MyArray<int> = new MyArray<int>();
```

or

```
MyArray<string> = new MyArray<string>();
```

Or anyother type you like

> How can I use the T array in the class?

Since we know that one of the common use of generics is to create collection classes. So you can also use it that way.

> Whether the array need to be created outside or inside in the class?

Question is little vague bcoz which class you are talking about the declaring class or the implementation class. But assuming that you are talking about the class where you implement or create the object of Class. It should be inside the class like normal object initiator.

Comment: You have opened my eyes to the mistake in my 4th question. The vagueness came about because although I do a lot of data processing, my understanding of theory is rather limited.

Comment: when I tried to initiate the class as suggested, it reported an error. So I tried MyArray<int> number = new MyArray<int>();. Please make a necessary edit to yur post. This is okay? @Mohit Shrivastava

Answer (score 2):

1: Yes, it's a class; hence the use of the `class` keyword.

2: `var myArray = new MyArray<Something>();` where `Something` could be any type (with maybe the odd exception).

3: From within the class, just refer to `array`. You won't be able to do a lot with the items themselves, though, since you don't know what type they are.

4: The code you posted creates the array inside the class. The array is hidden, and the only access to it is through the `GetItem` method. What you posted must be incomplete, though, since that would not be useful and would not work. You need to be able to do more than try to get an item.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [generic class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx). This means that `<T>` will be a type when it's instantiated. For example, based on your code example, you would instantiate it as:

```
MyArray<int> integerArray = new MyArray<int>();
```

This would instantiate a strongly typed array of integers. It does this by passing `T` throughout the class. The same class could be used to store strings by doing the following.

```
MyArray<string> stringArray = new MyArray<string>();
```

The reason for this is to allow container classes to be more flexible in terms of what types they can contain. This makes them more reusable. Before generics, if you wanted a dynamic list, you needed to use an `ArrayList` which cast everything to type `Object` and then required you to manually upcast it back to the type it was meant to be.

There are plenty of built in generic classes such as [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx), etc. They can be found in the `System.Generics` module.

Comment: Could you please add a little more to show exactly how both int and string are created using this. That would be a valuable help! @Soviut

Comment: @Unnikrishnan how string and int are created? They're not created, they're types.

Answer (score 1):

- *I would like to know if this is a class.*

> Yes this is a class and are called as [Generic Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx), A Generic
>   classes encapsulate operations that are not specific to a particular
>   data type. The most common use for generic classes is with collections
>   like linked lists, hash tables, stacks, queues, trees, and so on.
>   Operations such as adding and removing items from the collection are
>   performed in basically the same way regardless of the type of data
>   being stored.

- *How to instantiate this class?*

  ```
  MyArray<int> myArrayInstance= new MyArray<int>();
  ```
- *How can I use the T array in the class?*

You can use the name of the variable `array` to use them inside the class. and use the reference to access it from outside the class.

- *Whether the array need to be created outside or inside in the class*

You can populate the array inside the class or it can be populated from the MyArray Constructor. like the following:

```
public MyArray(T[] inputArrayElements)
{
   array = inputArrayElements;
}
```

- *Additional note, How to use GetItem*

You can use `myArrayInstance`, the instance of the class to call the method. the calling will be like the following:

```
int itemAtIndexs = myArrayInstance.GetItem<int>(5);
// which will give you the item @ 5th index
```

Comment: Can I upvote all the answeres as all are highly illustrative.

Answer (score 0):

I am preferring to post an answer based on what others guided me with the hope that it will be helpful people like me who are in the lower rung of C# and learning something new.

```
namespace GenericArray
{
    public class MyArray<T>
    {
        T[] array = new T[5];
        public MyArray(int size)
        { //Not used in this programme, because the no. of elements is already set above.
        }
        public void SetItem(int index, T value)
        {
            array[0] = value;
        }
        public T GetItem(int index)
        {
            return array[index];
        }
    }
}
```

In the button event, I code like this.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyArray<int> myInt = new MyArray<int>(5); //Initializing the generic class.
    myInt.SetItem(0, 1); //array element 0 is going to be assigned a value of 1.
    MessageBox.Show(myInt.GetItem(0).ToString());
    //You can also use the same class, to set string values.
}
```